# Informix 10 replication queues not moving

Tags: informix, database-replication

I'm using Informix IDS 10.00.UC6 on Solaris 10, with two machines having the same database schema and all tables replicating in both directions using Enterprise Replication, so in theory both databases should have the same content.

However , a problem has arisen where one direction of replication (Host A to Host B) continues to work correctly, but the other direction (Host B to host A) does not work. The symptoms are:

- Changes made to a table on Host B do not propagate to Host A (as determined by changing a row on Host B and inspecting the table on Host A)
- `cdr list serv` shows `Active` and `Connected` (both directions), but on Host B there is a queue of millions of bytes.
- `cdr list repl` shows non-zero queues for several of the replicates.
- `cdr stats recvq` on Host A shows nothing received from Host B recently.
- `cdr stats rqm` shows data in the spool `trg_send_stxn` with flags `SEND_Q, SPOOLED, PROGRESS_TABLE, NEED_ACK, SENDQ_MASK, SREP_TABLE`.
- There are no errors or relevant messages in `online.log` or `cdr_mon.log` , or any other place I can think to look.
- Some of the tables are "out of sync" in that rows have conflicting data or are missing; this is for various reasons relating to past errors where one host was offline. However, even changes to tables with correct data on Host B are not propagated to Host A.

  - I did a `cdr cleanstart` on Host B yesterday after this problem was occurring in both directions, which did at least make the A -> B direction start working (the opposite of what I expected), and the queue on Host B were 0 at that time.  After that cleanstart, some changes to tables (with correct data) would propagate to Host A, while some changes to other tables on B would not. But today, no tables are propagating from B to A.
  - Before the `cleanstart` I had found by experimenting that sometimes deleting an individual replicate would reduce the size of the stuck queue but the queue remained stuck all the same;  and sometimes, deleting a replicate would make the queue move for a time before being stuck again.
- There is also a DR host that both A and B do one-way propagation to, and that is propagating correctly with no queue backup.

I'm at a loss now as to try and diagnose why the data in the replication queues is not moving. If there were sync errors (i.e. the replicated change could not be applied due to Host A data differing) I would expect log messages in `online.log` that the update was rejected, with information saved to `$INFORMIXDIR/ats_dr` and so on -- this has happened recently .  It seems as if there must be something in the queue being refused but not being cleared and not logged, blocking the queue. Host A has heavy live traffic and (thankfully) is correctly replicating to Host B, but not vice versa.

Any ideas of more things to try or ways to diagnose the problem would be most welcome.

Edit - may or may not be related to [Retrieving or deleting a row with a blob in Informix 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208587/) where it appears that the ER send spooler on Host B has corruption.

Comment: As you're probably aware, version 10.00 is long out of service officially — so are the successor versions 11.10, 11.50, 11.70 (though 11.70 is only fairly recently at the end of life).  This makes it tricky for you to get help.  The upgrade path is tortuous too; I am not sure whether either 12.10 or 14.10 supports migration from 10.00.  You should review what changed to make things that had been working break.  Did you upgrade the o/s?  (I'm fairly sure 10.00 was not ported to Solaris 11, so the chances are high that there've been o/s changes since the DBMS was first installed.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah official support seems unlikely, hence hoping to find someone with experience to answer :) It is in fact Solaris 10, edited now.

Answer (score 2):

If there are any recent replication definition changes in your environment, I would look for the following for any clues. As Jonathan mentioned, IDS 10.0.xC6 is quite old and there were lots of addition to ER in the latest versions that makes it even more robust and resilient to failures

- Host B being Receive Only in the replicates
- ATS/RIS files

Comment: Unfortunately none of the ATS/RIS are generated in this scenario. Nothing has changed in the replication configuration for a long time. There was an unusual system crash (the database reported "out of virtual memory" for many operations but kept accepting other operations) which necessitated a restart, so it's possible that there is corrupt data in system tables somewhere, although I wouldn't know where to look or how to reset it

Answer (score 1):

What does cdr error -a show (run on each server)?

(Just in case you don't have it ... a link to Version 10 ER manual:
http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/25122792.pdf)

Oh, and are ALL Servers "in time sync" (ntp)?

JJ

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will review and see if I can learn something. The servers are in sync now, but were out by over 3 minutes when the problem originally started (not sure how that happened)

Comment: `cdr error -a` shows some errors from 2007 (!)  , nothing recent

Comment: This should possibly be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ATS/RIS files, can we assume all replicates do have these options on and this has already worked in the past?

What's in 'onstat -g rcv' (receive statistics) on A, and how does this output change over time?

What does 'onstat -g nif' say on B? Possibly a block in the transmission?

Can we assume both sides had been restarted at least once since the issue started so any internal thread confusion would have been resolved and ER re-initialized at least once on either side?

Is there possibly some huge transaction, from B underway to A, that's clogging replication, e.g. by filling up A's receive queue?  Any space problems in queue sbspaces (or queue header dbspaces)?

I guess a cleanstart on B will resolve the problem, but of course a re-sync of all replicated tables would have to occur (since you already did a cleanstart on A that's required anyway).

Andreas

Comment: Host A hasn't had a database or system restart (Host A is currently working fine and I'm loath to disturb that). Host B has had a full reboot and a cleanstart.   Yes, ATS/RIS has worked in the past (and still working I believe).   There is data stuck the send spooler as reported by `cdr stats rqm` and it may be corrupted , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208587/ for my other question.

Comment: OK, have reproduced the problem again. (To the DR host actually this time, so I think that shows it is definitely a problem with the outbound spooling on Host B).  `onstat -g nif` shows `nifGState RUN`  and some sent/received bytes to Host A and to DR Host .

Comment: `onstat -g rcv` on the DR host shows nothing at all from Host B (also supporting the theory that Host B is getting into a state where it fails to send at all)

Comment: `onstat -g rqm` on Host B shows `-12146621` bytes in queue for `trg_send_stxn` and it has had `418` txnsin spool for several days now, with `6` txns in memory