# Retrieving or deleting a row with a blob in Informix 10

Tags: sql, blob, informix

I'm using Informix 10. Using this command as suggested by [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=functions-lotofile-function) (well - the closest doc I could find):

```
select lotofile(ctbufdata, "foo!", "client") from trg_send_stxn where ctstamp1=60004300
```

(to database `syscdr`), it gives the error:

```
7420: Argument (1: lo_id) is invalid.
```

The same error occurs if I try to `unload to filename select * from`...

If I try to delete the row with `delete from trg_send_stxn where`...  , the error is:

```
(U00001) - blob_destroy: error during processing or invalid LO argument
```

How can I view this blob? (I want to view its contents to figure out where it came from).

Or; how can I delete it or otherwise recover from this apparent corruption.

---

As suggested in answers -- the command

```
select ("0x" || substr(ctbufdata::lvarchar,17,8))::INT sbspace
from trg_send_stxn
where ctstamp1=60004300
```

produces result `0`. And dropping the `where` clause produces 418 rows all `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since trg_send_stxn is an ER queue table, can we assume this is related to your other, ER related question ([Informix 10 replication queues not moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205312/informix-10-replication-queues-not-moving))? If so, is this on server A or B - I'd suspect B since this table is send queue related and you're reporting a problem from B to A?

In any case, this sounds like some sort of data corruption, either within the trg_send_stxn table's row (my guess), or in the actual sblob metadata pointed to by this row (ctbufdata column), i.e. in the sbspace.

Try selecting that row and displaying the LO pointer using technique described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/521537) (share output here).

Comment: Yeah it is related. I've just tried deleting all the replicants and recreating, and same problem; interestingly even though all the queue sizes went to `0` as reported by `cdr list repl`, there is still the same 418 entries in `trg_send_stxn`

Comment: Edited question to include the output of the suggested query

Comment: `oncheck -cS` on Host A returns 1 row while `oncheck -cS` on Host B returns about 4000 rows , even though no data is queued as reported by `cdr list repl`

Comment: Is there a way I can delete these rows or get rid of the corrupted blobs or whatever is going in?